# Implement google plus sharing in an android app

Tags: android, google-plus, sharing, google-api-client

I can't share to Google+ from my application, I am getting an error:

> ActivityNotFoundException

I have installed Google+ application on my device. Now I read also the documentation in developer.google.com and here they talk about the object `PlusClient`, that I can't find in my library. I also notice that the documentation was written in 2013.

So my question: Is `GoogleApiClient`, that I implemented to handler connection with Google play game services, used also for Google+? and how can I implement them with the new API version ?

Thanks at all for reply !

Comment: Your question is too ambiguous and broad. Try following a sample code and learn the subject, then if you still encounter a specific problem you should consult SO.

Comment: But by following the sample code i can't found the PlusClient object. I think that the PlusClient object was integrated in GoogleApiClient object